# Verificar se existe produtos em promoção no WordPress com WooCoomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Estou construindo um site WordPress com o WooCommerce e quero fazer a verificação de que se existe produtos em promoção com o shortcode, se existir me retorna o titulo  + produtos, se não existir nenhum produto em promoção o bloco some. Tive algumas ideias e uma delas foi a seguinte:

```
<?php
    //Produtos em promoção
    //Armazena o shortcode ( mas acredito estar errado ) 
    $produto_promocao = do_shortcode('[sale_products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="popularity" class="quick-sale" on_sale="true" ]'); 
    //Verifica se existe os produtos, se existir, exibe o titulo e os produtos por 
    //meio do shortcode, caso ao contrario, retorna vazio 
    if($produto_promocao != false){
        _e( 'Promotional Products', 'wordpress' ); //Exibe titulo
        echo $produto_promocao; //Exibe produtos
    } else { 
    return ''; //Retorna vazio
    }

?>
```

Mas não funcionou e imagino N motivos pra isso. Imagino que eu precise de algum identificador pros produtos em promoção, ou fazer alguma outra lógica.. Aceito criticas construtivas, estou treinando ! Peço desculpas de antemão já se eu não formatei aqui direito, sou iniciante. Abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala amigo, tudo bem?

Então cara, se eu entendi bem, você poderá exibir seus produtos em promoção dessa maneira abaixo:

```
<?php if( woo_have_onsale_products() ) { ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[products limit="4"  class="teste" columns="4" orderby="popularity" on_sale="true" ]'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div>Nenhum produto em promoção no momento.</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Se não achar necessário fazer a comparação com o ***else***, basta retirar e deixar apenas o ***if***.

Depois para que a sua lógica funcione perfeitamente, insira esse código abaixo na functions.php do seu tema:

```
function woo_have_onsale_products() {

global $woocommerce;
// Get products on sale
$product_ids_on_sale = array_filter( wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() ); // woocommerce_get_product_ids_on_sale() if WC < 2.1
if( !empty( $product_ids_on_sale ) ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}

}
```

Faz um teste aí e me dá um retorno.

Dá uma olhada também na página de documentação do woocommerce. Lá você terá várias outras opções de exibição para aplicar em seu tema.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Valeu!

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado ! Super funcionou, eu apenas acrescentei o titulo logo acima do echo do shortcode. Por gentileza, você poderia explicar sua linha de pensamento ? Gostaria de entender como você pensou para chegar a essa solução ! Abraços

Comment: Cara, basicamente eu criei uma função definindo uma variável e filtrando os ids dos produtos em promoção através do evento "wc_get_product_ids_on_sale", que vem do woocommerce, para poder fazer a comparação logo abaixo. Dá uma acessada nessa página ( https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/package-WooCommerce.Functions.html ), e veja os métodos disponíveis.

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente, e de uma forma um pouco mais simplificada acho que poderia ficar assim:

```php
if(woo_have_onsale_products()) {
  echo do_shortcode('[products limit="4"  class="teste" columns="4" orderby="popularity" on_sale="true" ]');
} else {
  echo '<div>Nenhum produto em promoção no momento.</div>';
}
```

e a função pra verificar se existem produtos on-sale ficaria:

```
function woo_have_onsale_products() {
  return !empty(wc_get_product_ids_on_sale());
}
```